# HighCharts Graph Issues

Tags: highcharts

We are using highcharts as part of the report generation. We generate 10 PDF reports simultaneously and we notice that there are instances that it shows incorrect information or sometimes no graphs are being displayed on some of the reports, but when we regenerate it, the issue no longer exists. The average successful report generation is 7 out of 10.

We are using PHP as our backend and we use cron to automate the processing of reports. We tried using sleep function but still getting the graph problem. The highcharts version that we are using is 4.1.4.

We are expecting that the report that we submitted (10), all of those should display the correct graph in the report

Comment: I would disable the animation first. Would be helpful if you could edit the question to share some code and more information as to where the report is generated _(PDF, HTML, sent in email, etc.)_

Comment: I have updated the question and put the version that we are using. We tried using the latest version 7.1 but still getting the same result of the missing graphs (image not found) - 3 out of 10 reports that we generated have issues.

Comment: Also, we got a message "sh: 1: highcharts-export-server: not found" but not sure if this causes this issue because most of the time the report is generated correctly.

Comment: Could you tell me which version of export server do you use? Also, is it the supported node export server version or deprecated Java and PhantomJS or PHP and Batik based solution?